# Pause issue JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to build a media player with JavaFX. First, I loaded a video, next I created pause button and work fine. When i load a new video with the open button ("apri") the video works but the pause button won't work properly -_- here my main class.. I don'have used the scenebuilder but I'm trying with only the code

```
public class Main extends Application {

public String indirizzo = "file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/film/prova1.mp4";

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        /* Creo la scena e mi faccio passare il media da visualizzare */

        /* Creo i pannelli */
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        StackPane sp = new StackPane();
        HBox hb = new HBox(5);
        VBox vb = new VBox();

        /* Primo video */
        MediaView mv = new MediaView();
        Media m = new Media(indirizzo);
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
        mv.setMediaPlayer(mp);
        mp.play();

        /* Creo gli oggetti nella parte bassa*/
        Slider misc = new Slider();
        Slider sl = new Slider();
        Label volume = new Label("Volume: ");

        Button btn1 = new Button("Apri");
        Button btn2 = new Button("<<");
        Button btn3 = new Button("| |");
        Button btn4 = new Button(">>");

        hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hb.setPadding(new Insets(5,10,5,10));
        /* Dimensioni slider */
        sl.setPrefWidth(70);
        sl.setMinWidth(30);
        sl.setValue(100);

        /* Posiziono i pannelli */
        bp.setCenter(mv);
        hb.getChildren().addAll(btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,volume,sl);


        vb.getChildren().addAll(misc,hb);
        bp.setBottom(vb);


        /* Se schiaccio il pulsante apri */
        btn1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

                    /* Prima metto in pausa il video */

                    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
                    ExtensionFilter filtro = new ExtensionFilter("Seleziona media (*.mp4)","*.mp4");
                    fc.getExtensionFilters().add(filtro);

                    /* Apro la finestra di dialogo per caricare il file */
                    File file = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                    indirizzo = file.toURI().toString();

                    if(file != null){
                        /* Carico il media nel mp */
                        Media m = new Media(indirizzo);

                        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
                        mv.setMediaPlayer(mp);
                        /* Imposto dimensione Media View*/
                        mv.setFitHeight(500);   /* Vanno bindate con la scene*/
                        mv.setFitWidth(500);
                        mp.play();

                        DoubleProperty mvw = mv.fitWidthProperty();
                        DoubleProperty mvh = mv.fitHeightProperty();
                        mvw.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "width"));
                        mvh.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "height"));
                        mv.setPreserveRatio(true);


                    }

                }
            });

        btn3.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            Status currentStatus = mp.getStatus();

            if(currentStatus == Status.PLAYING)
                mp.pause();
            else if(currentStatus == Status.PAUSED || currentStatus == Status.STOPPED){
                mp.play();
            }

        });


        Scene scena = new Scene(bp,500,500);
        scena.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scena);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the btn3 onAction method?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
               if(file != null){
                    /* Carico il media nel mp */
                    Media m = new Media(indirizzo);

                    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
```

You are using new variable `mp` which is not visible to `btn3.setOnAction()` handler.

To address that make `MediaPlayer mp` a class' field and don't introduce new variables with the `mp` name.